# RASA postback from Button click not working - Facebook Messenger

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-nlu, facebook-webhooks

Issue :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwf4h.png)
The Search Flight button is stopped working.
But the prompt "Search Flight" is working

Also , I can't see the log in webhook requests when I click the postback button

Note : To turn my local server endpoints to https endpoints, I used ngrok

Rasa version = 3.2.6

I tried to cross check these setup

Messanger Setup
Webhook Setup
messaging and messaging_postback subscriptions (is active.)

Code for Postback (Which is not directing to payload webhook URL)

```
"start_over_crsl": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
          {
            "title": "Flights ✈️",
            "image_url": "https://abcd-1.amazonaws.com/python-projects/abcd/flight.png",
            "subtitle": "Planning a trip? I will find you the best flight options!",
            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "postback",
                "title": "Search Flights",
                "payload": "/flight"
              }
            ]
          },
```

...

But suggestion chip is working perfectly (redirecting perfectly to webhook URL)

```
"quick_replies": [
  {
    "content_type": "text",
    "title": "✈️ Flights",
    "payload": "/flight"
  }, ...
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @СергейКох.
Now
I added the postbback code which is not working (Not redirecting to webhook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new policy came from Facebook. To access the webhook, the Chatbot Application needs to be live.

The issue is resolved by clicking Live toggle on the developer.facebook Application dashboard page.